# Hyperlink on Gmail Inbox view (content of email)

Tags: gmail, jakarta-mail

I am sending emails for my java web application. Right now i need to show a shortcut button to redirect to my webapp in inbox view like below. I spent almost 4 hours on this and cant get that. Can anyone help me to achieve this ?

[image: I need a button as like as in the image]

Comment: Check out the Actions section: https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/index

Answer (score 0):

What you are searching for are "Go-To Actions": https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/go-to-action

Here you can find an older answer on stackoverflow: [How to add link in subject of email (gmail)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23045754/how-to-add-link-in-subject-of-email-in-php-gmail)